# phpMyAdmin - Error > Incorrect format parameter?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have a WordPress production website.

I've exported the database by the following commands: `select database > export > custom > select all tables > select .zip compression > 'Go'`

I've downloaded the file which is example.sql.zip but when I upload to my localhost I get this error: `phpMyAdmin - Error > Incorrect format parameter`

I've tried to export with other formats and I get the same error.

I've tried with other SQL Databases and it exports/ imports just fine.

What could it be? A corrupt database or other?

Thanks

Comment: did you get the solution

Comment: nope. I'm surprised that there seems to be no support for this..

Comment: In my case, select a scheme/table (any) before throwing the query solved the problem...

Answer (score 669, accepted):

This issue is not because of corrupt database but rather the PHP upload size limit. It is suggested to increase the values of the following variables in `php.ini`:

```
upload_max_filesize=64M
post_max_size=64M
```

You may also want to increase the `max_exection_time` to a longer value for larger databases so it does not timeout while uploading.

Save you changes to the file and restart your PHP server.

Comment: Thanks for the idea which was a good one, however it still didn't work. I'm really out of ideas here...

Comment: Might as well increase the `max_exection_time` also because the database could be large and triggger a timeout.

Comment: that's correct.. both config together is a correct answer. not first item. I try to resolve by first item and cant. but when do second solved. thanks, StackOverflow thanks pooja.

Comment: [***See this question also***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691767/where-does-mamp-keep-its-php-ini) if you're using MAMP because you might have a hard time finding `php.ini`, like I did.

Comment: on linux to get your file size in M `ls -l --block-size=M`

Comment: Thank you. I did this on mamp and then restarted mamp. Everything is working perfect now.

Comment: I had the same problem, I was trying to upload the sql file which has very high file size about ~18MB but when I compressed the file it reduces to ~4 MB which fixed the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @VeeK you could correct your comment to "max_execution_time", then i delete mine :)

Comment: Jbtw, the correct spelling from @Whip comment is  `max_execution_time`

Comment: How can this be done if you spin up a docker container???

Comment: Yes this is old... There are 100 similar answers in a dozen questions. The missing piece for me after the changes were to RESTART THE SERVER. Simple, but essential. Thank you.

Answer (score 100):

Compress your `.sql` file, and make sure to name it `.[format].[compression]`, i.e. 
`database.sql.zip`.

As noted above, PhpMyAdmin throws this error if your `.sql` file is larger than the Maximum allowed upload size -- but, in my case the maximum was 50MiB despite that I had set all options noted in previous answers (look for the "Max: 50MiB" next to the upload button in PhpMyAdmin).

Comment: This worked for me. I had `max_execution_time=0` and `post_max_size=100M`, but an 80 MB file still gave an error. Zipping as `file.sql.zip` did the trick.

Comment: This solved my problem. My sql file was only slightly above the maximal size, but note that compressing can reduce the size significaltly: In my case 16-fold.

Comment: This helped me. I had 100MB set in php.ini and the file was generating the error at 46% of the upload, which was 43MB. I zipped it and no problem.

Comment: Simple and effective!

Comment: Actually, this issue because of Database Size.

Comment: Very Helpful. Be blessed.

Comment: Thank you - all the other answers are right, but if you somehow have server limits and the max upload size can't be changed in spite of setting it in options, this is an amazing (and hard-to-have-known) solution.

Comment: Thanks  @DesignGarden, 
I simply export the sql as .sql.gzip and then import it to another database and it works.

Answer (score 63):

For me, adjusting the 2 values was not enough. If the file is too big, you also need to adjust the execution time variables.

First, ../php/php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize=128M
post_max_size=128M
max_execution_time=1000
```

Then, ../phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 1000;
```

This did the trick for me. The variables can be choosen differently of course. Maybe the execution time has to be even higher. And the size depends on your filesize.

Answer (score 32):

None of these answers worked for me. I had to use the command line:

```
mysql -u root db_name < db_dump.sql
SET NAMES 'utf8';
SOURCE db_dump.sql;
```

Done!

Comment: Obrigado @Pedro! :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 21):

If you use docker-compose just set `UPLOAD_LIMIT`

```
phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
        UPLOAD_LIMIT: 1G
```

Comment: This is the correct way, it seems, from the default phpmyadmin docker image docs. I would like to add that if one is using nginx as a proxy pass, they must set proxy_read_timeout (i.e. `proxy_read_timeout 1500`).

Answer (score 18):

Just gone through the same problem when trying to import a CSV (400 MBs) and was also getting an error in red saying

> Error - incorrect format parameter

Initially thought it could have been the parameters and tested again. Faster, from my previous experince with it, I realized that it was due to other reasons (size of the file, execution of script has a maximum time defined, etc).

So, I've gone to php.ini

[image: php.ini]

and changed the values from the following settings

```
max_execution_time = 3000
max_input_time = 120
memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 1500M
upload_max_filesize = 1500M
```

After this modification, stoped MySQL and Apache and started them again, went to phpmyadmin trying to import. Then I reached another [error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13858161/5675325)

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded

which was fixed by simply setting in xampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/config.default.php

[image: config.default.php]

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

Setting it to 0 disables execution time limits.

Then, after a while, the import happened without problems.

Comment: Worked for me. +1 for well-detailed answer, clear instructions on what to change and how to change

Comment: You should edit `xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php` instead. The `config.default` file clearly states "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, EDIT config.inc.php INSTEAD"

Answer (score 11):

I got this error too, and I'm working with `ubuntu 20.04` and `PHP 8.0` so I solved the problem with these steps:

```
sudo nano /etc/php/8.0/apache2/conf.d/php.ini
```

in opened file find `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size`, `max_input_time`, `max_execution_time` by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> and increase the values like this:

```
max_execution_time = 3000
upload_max_filesize = 64M
max_input_time = 6000
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

save the INI file by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> and then close that by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>.

then restart your web server by this command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

> NOTE: These 4 parameters are not together and you have to find them
> one by one.

Comment: `/etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/(my name)_php.ini` <-- it may be a bit more in sync with the `conf.d` strategy to create a **new file** than to edit an existing one. As if to confirm, the default php.ini was moved out of there. I guess this worked for me because my file in conf.d was loaded after php.ini.

Answer (score 7):

Without any problems, I imported directly from the command line.

```
mysql -uroot -hURLServer -p DBName< filename.sql
```

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer to edit the file `php.ini` in your favorite editor than the Editor created by MAMP, you would need to stop the Servers first.

Then head to `Library->Application Support->appsolute->MAMP PRO->templates->php{version_number}.ini.temp` and effect any change you would want to have especially the below

```
max_execution_time = 3000
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 128M
post_max_size = 256M
upload_max_filesize 256M
```

And also make changes in your PHPMyAdmin if it is what you are using in Cpanel.

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;
```

Make sure you make a copy of the **original file**. You can navigate under **`conf`**!here

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem but with a docker container (phpmyadmin users),

Solution:

- Enter in the phpmyadmin container `docker exec -it idcontainer /bin/bash`
- Move `cd /usr/local/etc/php/`
- Create `php.ini` file
- Modify it `upload_max_filesize=128M
           post_max_size=128M
           max_execution_time=1000`
- Save and restart container.

This problem was in a Windows pc, at Linux i didnt need to do this.

Comment: i've docker container, i agree php.ini inside /usr/local/etc/php , already php.ini but continue error incorrect format parameter when import .sql in phpmyadmin

Comment: Ensure you restart the container after changes or it not gonna work.

Comment: Diego, that was probably b/c there are additional configuration files that are read after the initial php.ini file. Look at the ones in /usr/local/etc/php.d/*.ini. https://www.php.net/configuration.file

Answer (score 4):

Note: If you're using MAMP you MUST edit the file using the built-in editor.

Select PHP in the languages section (LH Menu Column) Next, in the main panel next to the default version drop-down click the small arrow pointing to the right.  This will launch the **`php.ini`** file using the MAMP text editor.  Any changes you make to this file will persist after you restart the servers.

Editing the file through `Application->MAMP->bin->php->{choosen the version}->php.ini` would not work. Since the application overwrites any changes you make.

Needless to say:  "Here be dragons!" so please cut and paste a copy of the original and store it somewhere safe in case of disaster.[image]

Answer (score 4):

On the command line use

```
C:\Windows\system32> mysql -u root -p

mysql> use desired_db;
mysql> source db_backup.sql;
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this by following the steps posted here: [xampp phpmyadmin, Incorrect format parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201874/xampp-phpmyadmin-incorrect-format-parameter)

Because I'm not using XAMPP, I also needed to update my `php.ini.default` to `php.ini` which finally did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

If You are using wampp and windows 11
open folder
**C:\wamp64\alias\phpmyadmin.conf**

update values

```
php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
php_admin_value max_input_time 360
```

to

```
php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 1028M
php_admin_value post_max_size 1028M
php_admin_value max_execution_time 3600
php_admin_value max_input_time 3600
```

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by the fact that the maximum upload size is (Max: 2,048KiB). If your file is bigger than this, you will get an error. Zip the file and upload it again, you will not get the error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error and as I'm on shared hosting I don't have access to the php.ini so wasn't sure how I could fix it, the host didn't seem to have a clue either.  In the end I emptied my browser cache and reloaded phpmyadmin and it came back!

Answer (score 1):

You can use xampp shell

1. Open Xampp and click shell
   [image]

Type the following command
mysql -u username -p -v database_name < "/path/file.sql"

example : username :root

```
      password : leave blank
```

database_name is the database you are importing to (create this database before importing)

Answer (score 1):

**Solved!** with 2 simple steps.

1. in php.ini

   max_execution_time = 600

   max_input_time = 600

   memory_limit = 1024M

   post_max_size = 1024M
2. my.ini

   max_allowed_packet = 1024M

Answer (score 0):

If you can't upload import file due to big size and you can't modify parameters because you are in a shared hosting try to install on your computer HeidiSQL and load file from there.

Answer (score 0):

This tends to occur when you change the PHP settings as mentioned here and continue to import the database without first restarting Apache. That causes the error to be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have used this approach, simply export the database as .sql.gzip and then import it where we needed. It basically reduce the file size and make it easy to import the sql file.

It helps me and hopefully can help others too.

Answer (score -2):

None of the above answers solved it for me.

I cant even find the 'libraries' folder in my xampp - ubuntu also.

So, I simply restarted using the following commands:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and

```
sudo service mysql restart

Just restarted apache and mysql. Logged in phpmyadmin again and it worked as usual.
```

Thanks me..!!