# how to import database into phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, wampserver

I have a following problem I want to import  my database into phpmyadmin but I am facing  following error
**phpMyAdmin - Error
Incorrect format parameter**

I change already php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 600MB
post_max_size = 600MB
max_exection_time =3000
```

I had wamp server previously and it was working correctly but I needed php 7.4 version so I uninstalled wamp and installed xamp instead and now it is not working. Do you have any ideas what can be a reason?

Comment: Have you restarted xampp server after changing php.ini

Comment: yes  I restarted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [phpMyAdmin - Error > Incorrect format parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50690076/phpmyadmin-error-incorrect-format-parameter)

Comment: no, I used command line ad It worked

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:
in php.ini try to change `memory_limit`
something like
`memory_limit=300M`

restart server(!)

---

You can easily import using cmd promt:

```
mysql -u *username* -p *password* database_name < your/file.sql
```