# I can't upload sql file on phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, php-8

I downloaded the sql file of the project I have and wanted to upload it to phpMyAdmin on localhost. But every time I want to load I get `Incorrect format parameter` error. The size of my file is also 32 MB. When I searched for the solution to the problem, I found [phpMyAdmin - Error > Incorrect format parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50690076/phpmyadmin-error-incorrect-format-parameter) answers on Stack Overflow. However, when I applied the answers here, nothing changed. For some reason I can't change it (Max: 8,192KiB). I am using 8.0.8 as the php version in MAMP and I made these changes in the 8.0.8 php.ini file among the files. So I think I didn't do anything wrong, but for some reason I couldn't solve the problem. I'm putting my php.ini file below, you can check it from there.

**Here is my 8.0.8 php.ini**

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 64M

; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 64M
```

Comment: how you verified that filesize is the problem here? Tried uploading smaller file?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski When I first tried, the places I specified in the code block were 8M, and when I searched the internet, I found this only way as a solution. I also changed the relevant fields as specified, but the (Max: 8,192KiB) part on phpMyAdmin does not change. Doesn't that part need to change anyway, depending on the changes I've made?

Comment: First, you said nothing how your phpmyadmin is setup. If it runs via httpd, i.e. apache, then check vhost config as some limits can be set there. Also note that usually you can have more than one `php.ini` (i.e. `cli` and `apache`) and you must edit correct one (just do `phpinfo()` and search for the path of used php.init. Finally -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958615/import-file-size-limit-in-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with a friend on another forum. He told me to approach it from a different perspective. He said, instead of increasing the maximum upload size, reduce the file you will upload. In short, if you are getting the same error, first compress the sql file you want to upload into a .zip file and try to install it that way. Most likely your problem will be solved. I wish you less error days:)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).