# importing db phpMyAdmin - Error Incorrect format parameter

Tags: mysql, import, parameters, export

I am trying to import the production mysql db into a local xampp test environment. By connecting to web admin(mozff) and simple exporting sql(never needed anything else).And then go to local phpmyadmin dashboard and import. It is throwing the following errors

**Error:**

[image]

**Live Environment:**

Db-Server

```
Server: db01.l2.url.com via TCP/IP
Server-Typ: MariaDB
Server-Version: 10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 - Debian 9.1
Protokoll-Version: 10
User: user
Server-encoding: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

Webserver

```
Apache
Datenbank-Client Version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: b5c5906d452ec590732a93b051f3827e02749b83 $
PHP-Erweiterung: mysqliDokumentation curlDokumentation mbstringDokumentation
PHP-Version: 7.0.27-0+deb9u1
```

phpMyAdmin

```
Version informationen: 4.6.6deb4
```

**Test Environment**

DB-Server

```
Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server-Typ: MariaDB
Server-connection: SSL not used
Server-Version: 10.1.33-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
Protokoll-Version: 10
user: root@localhost
Server-encoding: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

Webserver

```
Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0h PHP/7.2.6
Datenbank-Client Version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387 $
PHP-extension: mysqliDokumentation curlDokumentation mbstringDokumentation
PHP-Version: 7.2.6
```

phpMyAdmin

```
Version informationen: 4.8.1, aktuelle stabile Version: 4.8.2
```

**Question:**

1. Where do I see what parameter is incorrect?
2. I am assuming mysql 4.8.1 db is backwards compatible with 4.6.6deb4
   ..??

**what I have tried:**

[phpMyAdmin - Error > Incorrect format parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50690076/phpmyadmin-error-incorrect-format-parameter)

[xampp phpmyadmin, Incorrect format parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201874/xampp-phpmyadmin-incorrect-format-parameter)

**Logs:**

```
180709 11:52:25   246 Connect   pma@localhost as anonymous on 
          247 Connect   root@localhost as anonymous on 
          247 Query SELECT @@version, @@version_comment
          247 Query SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci'
          247 Query SET lc_messages = 'de_DE'
          246 Query SELECT `config_data`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timevalue`) ts FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__userconfig` WHERE `username` = 'root'
          246 Query SELECT `config_data`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timevalue`) ts FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__userconfig` WHERE `username` = 'root'
          247 Query SET collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
          247 Init DB   mysql
          247 Query SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS'
180709 11:52:26   247 Quit  
          246 Quit  
180709 11:52:33   248 Connect   pma@localhost as anonymous on 
          249 Connect   root@localhost as anonymous on 
          249 Query SELECT @@version, @@version_comment
          249 Query SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci'
          249 Query SET lc_messages = 'de_DE'
          248 Query SELECT `config_data`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timevalue`) ts FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__userconfig` WHERE `username` = 'root'
          249 Query SET collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
          249 Query SELECT `SCHEMA_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`SCHEMATA`, (SELECT DB_first_level FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SCHEMA_NAME, '_', 1) DB_first_level FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE TRUE ) t ORDER BY DB_first_level ASC LIMIT 0, 100) t2 WHERE TRUE AND 1 = LOCATE(CONCAT(DB_first_level, '_'), CONCAT(SCHEMA_NAME, '_')) ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME ASC
          248 Query SELECT `db_name`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__navigationhiding` WHERE `username`='root' GROUP BY `db_name`
          249 Query SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SCHEMA_NAME, '_', 1) DB_first_level FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE TRUE ) t
          249 Query SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SCHEMA_NAME, '_', 1) DB_first_level FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE TRUE ) t
          248 Query SELECT * FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__bookmark` WHERE ( `user` = '' OR `user` = 'root' ) ORDER BY label ASC
          249 Quit  
          248 Quit  
180709 11:52:51   250 Connect   pma@localhost as anonymous on 
          251 Connect   root@localhost as anonymous on 
          251 Query SELECT @@version, @@version_comment
          251 Query SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci'
          251 Query SET lc_messages = 'de_DE'
          250 Query SELECT `config_data`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timevalue`) ts FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__userconfig` WHERE `username` = 'root'
          251 Query SET collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
180709 11:52:52   251 Quit  
          250 Quit  
180709 11:52:53   252 Connect   pma@localhost as anonymous on 
          253 Connect   root@localhost as anonymous on 
          253 Query SELECT @@version, @@version_comment
          253 Query SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci'
          253 Query SET lc_messages = 'de_DE'
          252 Query SELECT `config_data`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timevalue`) ts FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__userconfig` WHERE `username` = 'root'
          253 Query SET collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
          253 Query SELECT `SCHEMA_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`SCHEMATA`, (SELECT DB_first_level FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SCHEMA_NAME, '_', 1) DB_first_level FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE TRUE ) t ORDER BY DB_first_level ASC LIMIT 0, 100) t2 WHERE TRUE AND 1 = LOCATE(CONCAT(DB_first_level, '_'), CONCAT(SCHEMA_NAME, '_')) ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME ASC
          252 Query SELECT `db_name`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__navigationhiding` WHERE `username`='root' GROUP BY `db_name`
          253 Query SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SCHEMA_NAME, '_', 1) DB_first_level FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE TRUE ) t
          253 Query SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SCHEMA_NAME, '_', 1) DB_first_level FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE TRUE ) t
180709 11:52:54   253 Quit  
          252 Quit  
          254 Connect   pma@localhost as anonymous on 
          255 Connect   root@localhost as anonymous on 
          255 Query SELECT @@version, @@version_comment
          255 Query SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci'
          255 Query SET lc_messages = 'de_DE'
          254 Query SELECT `config_data`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timevalue`) ts FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__userconfig` WHERE `username` = 'root'
          255 Query SET collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
      254 Quit  
      256 Connect   pma@localhost as anonymous on 
      257 Connect   root@localhost as anonymous on 
      257 Query SELECT @@version, @@version_comment
      257 Query SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci'
      257 Query SET lc_messages = 'de_DE'
      256 Query SELECT `config_data`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timevalue`) ts FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__userconfig` WHERE `username` = 'root'
      257 Query SET collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
      256 Query SELECT `config_data`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timevalue`) ts FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__userconfig` WHERE `username` = 'root'
      256 Query SELECT `username` FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__userconfig` WHERE `username` = 'root'
      256 Query UPDATE `phpmyadmin`.`pma__userconfig` SET `timevalue` = NOW(), `config_data` = '{\"lang\":\"de\",\"Console\\/Mode\":\"collapse\"}' WHERE `username` = 'root'
```

180709 11:52:58   257 Quit
          256 Quit

Comment: Did you find an answer to this issue?  I'm having the same problem on MAMP.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and tried many things especially increasing the time limits in `php.ini` but nothing really worked. Finally I did the job my importing the sql file via command line:

`mysql -u username -p databasename < /path/to/file.sql`

In most cases the username would be just `root`. If you have same tables in both the old database and new database backup file, then you may get an error like this:

`ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 31: Table 'wp_commentmeta' already exists`

In that case, drop (delete) existing database and then import the new file via the command stated above.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error on MAMP i resolve by changing the parameters in php.ini

I followed the instruction by Timmy @[enter link description here](https://timmyomahony.com/blog/MAMP-phpmyadmin-and-big-database-imports-errors-or-timeouts/)

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
post_max_size = 256M



; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 256M

; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_execution_time = 600     

; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
max_input_time = 600

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (8MB)
memory_limit = 512M
```

NOTE1: you can replace values by your own e.g. one can write 5000 in place of 600

NOTE2: restart your Xampp or MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

use command line (CMD)
https://youtu.be/gdyD3gFrahU
i use this way for importing database with 1.14G, if you don't want to edit your PHP.ini file, i suggest you to trying this way