# phpMyAdmin - Error Incorrect format parameter

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to import a large sql file but its not getting imported. 
And it shows the following error.

**phpMyAdmin - Error
Incorrect format parameter**

I have been using Xampp-php 5.6 in ubuntu16.04.

I have tried these links given below already but none of it worked.

https://www.webtrickshome.com/forum/how-to-fix-phpmyadmin-error-incorrect-format-parameter-that-appeared-while-importing-a-database

[importing db phpMyAdmin - Error Incorrect format parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240993/importing-db-phpmyadmin-error-incorrect-format-parameter?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Importing large database file in MAMP phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52853737/importing-large-database-file-in-mamp-phpmyadmin)

Comment: please restart server once you made changes

Comment: Yeah..I did..but same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily import using cmd promt

```
mysql -u username(of phpmyadmin) -p database_name < file_path/file_name.sql
```

you can also do the changes in php.ini file to increase upload size of phpmyadmin.

in php.ini of your PHP installation (note: depending if you want it for CLI, Apache, or Nginx, find the right php.ini to manipulate)

```
post_max_size=500M

upload_max_filesize=500M

memory_limit=900M
```

or set other values.

Restart/reload apache if you have apache installed or php-fpm for nginx if you use nginx.

Remote server?

increase max_execution_time as well, as it will take time to upload the file.

NGINX installation?

you will have to add: client_max_body_size 912M; in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf to the http{...} block

Comment: I changed the things you said above and tried already.But nothing changed. And I tried that command too but it needs mysql server which is already installed to start running and not the installed xampp.

Comment: There is no such database.

Comment: the name of the database you are typing while using command is wrong, so please write correct databasename or create the database with the same name you are using in command

Comment: OK..but i want that db to be created in my xampp phpmyadmin ..Is it correct to do that.

Comment: phpmyadmin is just a tool to create database in mysql. it is the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem when I was trying to import a 90mb database. You can solve this problem by opening

```
xampp->phpMyadmin->libraries->config.default.php
```

after opening the file search for `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;`

Here you can set the time to 1000 or whatever you want after the equal sign. The default value is 300.

Answer (score 2):

thanks for thi answer
post_max_size=500M

upload_max_filesize=500M

memory_limit=900M

Answer (score 1):

There file format can be .sql.zip
Shown in the attached picture. It happened to me.

[image]